# What GPT partition type GUID should I use for a VeraCrypt partition?

Tags: windows, partitioning, truecrypt, gpt, veracrypt

I am attempting to set up a VeraCrypt partition so that it will auto-mount in Windows using the Favorites feature. However, the message I get from VeraCrypt (which is the same as what TrueCrypt use to say) is:

> The volume you are adding to favorites is a partition not recognized by Windows. VeraCrypt will be unable to mount this favorite volume if the device number changes. Please set the type of the partition to a type recognized by Windows (use the SETID command of the Windows 'diskpart' tool). Then add the partition to favorites again.

That message is somewhat frustrating because it does not state what ID to use for either MBR or GPT partitions. There are certain Microsoft standard partition types that will cause the drive to attempt to automount natively in Windows, which is bad because Windows will ask to format the drive.

So I'm looking for a partition type (in GPT for my case) that will not trigger Windows to ask for formatting, but will still get a volume ID in Windows. It's also necessary that the type doesn't prevent the partition from working the same way in Linux, but I assume that Linux will naturally be less picky about it than Windows is.

Answer (score 1):

I was faced with the same problem some time ago, the solution I found is to set the type to:

**Linux Reserved**, GUID `8DA63339-0007-60C0-C436-083AC8230908`

So to recap, make sure to dismount the partition first, then in `diskpart.exe`:

1. `list disk`
2. `select disk <disk#>`
3. `list partition`
4. `select partition <part#>`
5. `setid id=8DA63339-0007-60C0-C436-083AC8230908`

Hope this helps

Comment: I get "The specified type is not in the correct format. For more information on the command type: HELP SET" Copied ID from HELP, still get the above. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem today. I found Dalva's solution worked for me with slight modifications.

I had to use a different GUID, one that was "recognized by Windows". I chose

```
Basic data partition:
    ebd0a0a2-b9e5-4433-87c0-68b6b72699c7
```

Afterwards, I went to Windows "Disk Management" (in Control Center) and removed the drive letter. After that, I could add the disk as favorite in VeraCrypt an mount it.

Comment: I think this one may be problematic since Windows may ask to format it, or may try to use BitLocker to encrypt it if a group policy requires that.

Comment: On my Windows 10, it does not ask to format it, as long as the drive letter is removed from the (encrypted) partition. The drive letter is not needed anyway, since VeraCrypt will assign a drive letter after decryption and mounting. I don't have any experience with BitLocker. I don't see added value in enabling BitLocker if the partitions are already encrypted with VeraCrypt.

Comment: It's not a matter of value add - it would literally break VeraCrypt. The problem is that in some situations, a shared group policy may require that all data partitions be encrypted, and if Windows thinks it understands a partition, it will proceed to force it to be Bitlocker-encrypted.

Comment: I get "The specified type is not in the correct format. For more information on the command type: HELP SET" Copied ID from HELP, still get the above. Any ideas?