# How to hide a VeraCrypt partition from Windows Explorer?

Tags: windows, windows-10, partitioning, veracrypt

My question is kind of opposite of [What GPT partition type GUID should I use for a VeraCrypt partition?](https://superuser.com/q/1450660/) and I don't like a solution like https://superuser.com/a/1438051/:

I have an USB stick consisting of two primary partitions, a "normal" one and an encrypted one (using veraCrypt).
The stick uses MBR partitioning.

When I plug in the stick, Windows assigns a drive letter and prompts for formatting the partition.
Obviously **I don't want to format the partition**, so I'd like to make Windows ignore the partition.

I used Linux to set the partition type to 0x1e ("Hidden W95 FAT16 (LBA)"), but that did not hide the partition from Windows 10.

Is there a way to make Windows ignore the encrypted partition?

I'm looking for a change to the stick, not for a change on Windows as I want to use the stick on multiple systems (Windows and Linux).

Comment: I would be inclined to have 2 sticks. One encrypted and one not encrypted. Vastly easier.

Comment: And then Windows will not suggest to format the encrypted one? Despite of that the first partition is only 1MB and it has only a `README.txt` file stating who is the legal owner of the stick ;-)

Comment: Do not insert the encrypted stick in a Windows machine. That was my point.

Comment: Use an encrypted file (folder) rather than encrypted partition. You can put the encrypted data on any partition.

Comment: Just use any type that Windows doesn't use / recognize (e.g. 0x83).

Comment: @Tom Yan Shouldn't it be the list the "windows leaves alone" rather than "Windows does not know"? The types Windows does not know could become smaller over time.

Comment: @John Obviously if I don't insert the stick to a Windows system, I would not have any Widows issue, but that's really not helpful for the question.

Answer (score 0):

When using ["USB Drive Letter Manager" (USBDLM)](https://www.uwe-sieber.de/usbdlm_e.html) you can add these lines to `USBDLM.ini` to prevent assigning a drive letter when the partition seems to contain random data (`TrueCrypt`) or when access to the partition is denied (`ReadSharingViolation`):

```ini
[DriveLetters]
DeviceType1=TrueCrypt
DeviceType2=ReadSharingViolation
```

See [USBDLM Help on Configuration](https://www.uwe-sieber.de/usbdlm_help_e.html#config) for details.
Note that VeraCrypt is treated as TrueCrypt here.